# camel XPATH variable to XQuery element() convert problem

Tags: apache-camel, xquery

In Apache camel I need to extract a xml element and pass it to xquery as
element(), but i have strange error. 
Any idea and suggesions are more than welcome!

Camel code:

```
from(SOAP_ENDPOINT_IN_URI + "&dataFormat=CXF_MESSAGE") 
.setHeader("CMDRequest",  XPathBuilder.xpath("//*[local-name() = 
'CMDRequest']")
```

Xquery code:

```
declare variable $in.headers.CMDRequest as element() external ;
```

Error:

> Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Required item type of value of variable $in.headers.GetDeltaCustomerRequest is element(); supplied value has item type Q{http://saxon.sf.net/java-type}com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList

Comment: It looks like your `XPathBuilder.xpath` method works with Apache Xalan's dtm object model and returns a `DTMNodeList` while your XQuery code uses Saxon and Saxon doesn't know to handle the Xalan result of that type other than wrapping it as a Java object. I am not familiar with Camel, you need to find out whether you can configure it to use Saxon both for XQuery and XPath, then I would hope chances are high the interaction works.

Comment: See http://camel.apache.org/xpath.html, it has some sections on using Saxon for XPath, perhaps that helps solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks your xpath is returning a **list** of elements and not a single element. This could be fixed by by taking the first item of the array of CMDRequest's  (assuming list is never empty):

```
.setHeader("CMDRequest",  XPathBuilder.xpath("(//*[local-name()='CMDRequest'])[1]")
```

Comment: i even tried from(SOAP_ENDPOINT_IN_URI + "&dataFormat=CXF_MESSAGE") 
.setHeader("CMDRequest",  XPathBuilder.xpath("//*[local-name() = 
'CMDRequest']", org.w3c.dom.Element.class) still does not work